# Is it possible to create web pages in C++?

Tags: c++, web, web-development-server

I see on some Wikipedia pages of the websites such as Quora that they are written in C++. If the web languages are HTML, CSS and JavaScript what is the reasoning behind creating web pages in C++?

Comment: You're confusing web pages (in the browser) with web servers.

Answer (score 2):

There are typically two different components to a website. First, there’s what gets sent to the browser. That ends up being JavaScript, HTML, and CSS, usually with some other images or resources thrown in.

But something has to be sitting on the server to handle incoming connections and then decide *which* JavaScript, HTML, and CSS to send to the browser to display, and that can be written in many different languages. Sometimes you’d use C++ for speed here, but many other languages (Python, Java, C#, PHP, JavaScript, etc.) can be used to do this step.

Answer (score 1):

You can use C++ to *generate* pages (like PHP does) and/or handle the users' browser requests (= web server).
In other words, the user will typically receive HTML, CSS, JS and other resources (audio, images, video) - not what is used exclusively server-side.
If you generate pages using C++, you will want to generate HTML. There are tools that allow you to get your page generator working with a web server, namely nginx and Apache.

That being said, it is possible to use C++ to program the scripting side you would typically do in JS, using a tool such as [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten). This sort of technology is often used for "web exports" in game engines, such as UE, Unity or GM:S (if my memory serves right). In the end, though, JS (or more recently WebAssembly) will be used for this purpose.